# How would I make a subtle curved line divider between two images?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

As such: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdHNE.png

CSS border, clip path, etc?

I've tried the following:

```css
div#box{
  width: 38px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 13px solid black;
  border-color: transparent black transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 0 100% 100% 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

But it's not giving me the result I'm looking for (the curve is too subtle).

I've also tried using clip path but the transparent element won't "cut" into the other one obviously since it's transparent.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.one {
  height: 500px;
  width: 38px;
  background-color: white;
  clip-path: ellipse(38px 50% at 0% 50%);
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  top: 0;
}
.two {
  height: 500px;
  width: 38px;
  background-color: transparent;
  clip-path: ellipse(38px 50% at 0% 50%);
  position: absolute;
  right: calc(50% + 13px);
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We are not here to do your homework. What have you tried, what worked and what didn't?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Try to clip both containers instead of creating the white gap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Can you please try this and only play with second[180%] and third[-2%] value.**

In here we create a required `clip-path` than we create another div which will create us a middle space and aplly `position: absolute` ,`overflow:hidden` to create same clip-path in red div and than we set `background-color` of middle div as same as screens background-color.

`z-index` are need to be .one > .middle > .two

```
clip-path: ellipse(100% 180% at -2% 50% )
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  place-items: center;
  background-color: bisque;
}


.one{
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: green;
  clip-path: ellipse(100% 180% at -2% 50% ) ;
  z-index: 3;
}

.middle{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  clip-path: ellipse(100% 180% at -2% 50% ) ;
  left:25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: bisque;
}
.two{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  right:25px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="middle"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
```